# Rename a file in a directory without retyping the directory name

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

Say we have a file `test.txt` in `my_directory` that I want to rename to `yeah.txt`.
Is there a way with `zsh` (or even just `bash`, just to know) to avoid retyping `my_directory`?

I find the following a bit long:

```
mv my_directory/test.txt my_directory/yeah.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it with brace expansion:

```
mv my_directory/{test,yeah}.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I have `copy-prev-shell-word` assigned to `^P`

```
% cp my_directory/test.txt [^P] # expands to....
% cp my_directory/test.txt my_directory/test.txt
```

Then I just manually edit the last argument. For me this is a better solution than brace expansion, but I reckon it is just a preference.

If interested, you should look at one of these functions (`man zshzle`):

```
copy-prev-word (ESC-^_) (unbound) (unbound)
 Duplicate the word to the left of the cursor.

copy-prev-shell-word
 Like  copy-prev-word,  but  the  word  is  found  by  using  shell  parsing,
 whereas copy-prev-word  looks for blanks. This makes a difference when the 
 word is quoted and contains spaces.
```

I use this to bind the function `bindkey -M emacs "^p" copy-prev-shell-word`